# ContactDetailActivity from Lockscreen Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, lockscreen

I have created a lockscreen widget that starts a custom activity when a click is performed on it. This activity displays a few predefined user selected contact names. When the user click on one of these names, I would like to display contact's information.

Since I have the contact ID when I click on the contact display name, I use an intent to redirect to the builtin [ContactDetailActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/61414c2c4627ab588cc0f54eae5e0c5591f7d8d9/src/com/android/contacts/activities/ContactDetailActivity.java) by using the following piece of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Uri uri =
        Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactId));

intent.setData(uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

The problem is that I have to unlock the screen to see the contact activity that displays information. I think the problem is due to the fact that I haven't specified flag [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED) for `ContactDetailActivity`, however I cannot figure out how to do nor if it is possible?

Is there a simple mean to achieve my purpose. Otherwise, the last solution I see is to create a custom activity that behaves like `ContactDetailActivity` so that I can put the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` flag. However, it seems overkill.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use `QuickContactBadge` instead ? here android has good tutorial in how to use it [Android Displaying the Quick Contact Badge](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/display-contact-badge.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am investigating what you have proposed but I am not sure `QuickContactBadge` has rights by default to display contact information on lockscreen. I come back once I have tested.

Comment: I have tried to use QuickContactBadge but the issue is the same, when a QuickContactBadge is created from a lock screen activity, the screen must be unlocked to display the popup :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not dismiss the keyguard when launching the activity with `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`?

Comment: Because this flag works only if the keyguard is not a secure lock keyguard.

Comment: Then you would have to use `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` if you want it to be available with secure lockscreens. However, it would be better if its not available on a secure lockscreen. I wouldn't like people snooping on my contacts. Just an opinion.

Comment: That's the issue, I don't have control over ContactDetailActivity which is a builtin android activity that is started with an intent. If you know how to set `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` for an activity started with an intent please help. My goal is to display  information for contacts the owner has selected. Consequently, privacy is not the problem here!

Comment: It is not possible to set `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` to an external activity.